# Seeking related work to cocomplete category with "compatibility relation"

Tags: category-theory, lattice-orders

I am looking for related work that matches a set-up as follows:

Consider a cocomplete category $\mathsf X$ (i.e. a category with all colimits), and a **compatibility relation** $\ast$ that is a functor
$$
\ast : \mathsf X \times \mathsf X \to \mathsf X
$$
such that $\ast$ is commutative (i.e. $x \ast x' = x' \ast x$; this may be on-the-nose or a natural transformation), and $\ast$ commutes with colimits on both components.

A simple example of this set-up is where $\mathsf X$ is a lattice, and $x\ast x'$ just returns $x\wedge x'$.

Other targets on the right-hand side are also possible, i.e.
$$
\ast : \mathsf X \times \mathsf X \to\mathsf Y
$$
where $\mathsf Y$ is a cocomplete category.  Again to take a simple example, $\mathsf Y$ may be a lattice of truth-values, such as $\mathsf{Bool}$.

I welcome references to related work.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with monoidal categories?

Comment: A cocomplete closed and symmetric monoidal category would work

Comment: @S.C. Thank you: yes, this is a good observation.

Comment: @FShrike Thank you.  Two questions:
* Is it assumed in a cocomplete symmetric monoidal category that the monoidal action preserves colimits on both components?  
* I was not familiar with the notion of a closed category; I looked up the definition, but it was not immediately obvious (to me) how this connects with the description in my question.
It would be great if there were families of such structures that I might cite as related work.

Comment: A monoidal category $(\mathscr{V};\otimes)$ is closed if there are objects $\underline{\mathscr{V}}(a,b)\in\mathscr{V}$ for every $a,b\in\mathscr{V}$ and isomorphisms: $\mathscr{V}(a\otimes b,c)\cong\mathscr{V}(a,\underline{\mathscr{V}}(b,c))$ (among all $a,b,c\in\mathscr{V}$) which are natural in $a$. Because then we may define $\underline{\mathscr{V}}$ as a bifunctor $\mathscr{V}\times\mathscr{V}\to\mathscr{V}$ making those isomorphisms natural in all three variables, and it follows that each product functor $x\mapsto x\otimes a$ has a right adjoint (so is cocontinuous)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is essentially the notion of *(symmetric) [monoidally cocomplete category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monoidally+cocomplete+category)*, which is a [cocomplete](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocomplete+category) [symmetric monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/symmetric+monoidal+category) whose tensor product is [cocontinuous](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocontinuous+functor) in each argument. As mentioned in the comments, every cocomplete [closed monoidal category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category) is monoidally cocomplete, since in this case the tensor is left-adjoint and hence preserves arbitrary colimits.

For instance, see the introduction to Im–Kelly's [A universal property of the convolution monoidal structure](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404986900058), which I believe is where the concept was first named.

Comment: Upvote for being the author of the Quiver app. 